# How to find product with maximum order quantity in each region?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to find product with maximum order quantity in each region. Result should be like this:

| `RegionID | ProductID` |

Here is database:

[image]

P.S link to database backup:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15iE53xxni9C7uGaaa-kcK4b6WnmQv_1f

This is my code, i tried but it calculates only for one Region. I need to calculate dynamically for all regions.

```
SELECT TOP 1 T.RegionID, T.ProductID, MAX(T.Quantity) AS MaxOrders
FROM(
    SELECT Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID, SUM([Order Details].Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM Region
    JOIN Territories ON Region.RegionID = Territories.RegionID
    JOIN EmployeeTerritories ON Territories.TerritoryID = EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID
    JOIN Employees ON EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
    JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
    JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
    GROUP BY Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID
) T
WHERE T.RegionID = 1
GROUP BY T.RegionID, T.ProductID
ORDER BY MaxOrders DESC
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: it is image of database schema not code

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the partition to achieve this, I have joined the necessary table according to your diagram.

```
        SELECT REGIONID,PRODUCTID
        FROM(SELECT *,Row_number() over(partition by REGIONID order by Total desc) rn
        FROM(Select T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID,COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID) as Total
        From Orders O
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories ET
        on O.EmployeeID=ET.EmployeeID
        LEFT JOIN Territories T
        on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
        LEFT JOIN OrderDetails OD
        on OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
        GROUP BY T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID)a)b
    WHERE b.rn=1
```

Since you want an alternate without partition you can have a subquery to `have the max product sales amount for each region and use it to join in order to get the max sales product per region.

```
SELECT a.RegionID,a.PRODUCTID
(Select T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID,COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID) as Total
    From Orders O
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories ET
    on O.EmployeeID=ET.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN Territories T
    on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails OD
    on OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
    GROUP BY T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID)a
INNER JOIN
(Select RegionID,max(Total) as MaXTotal
FROM(Select T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID,COUNT(OD.PRODUCTID) as Total
    From Orders O
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories ET
    on O.EmployeeID=ET.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN Territories T
    on T.TerritoryID=ET.TerritoryID
    LEFT JOIN OrderDetails OD
    on OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
    GROUP BY T.REGIONID,OD.PRODUCTID)b
GROUP BY RegionID)c
on c.RegionID=a.RegionID and a.Total=c.MaxTotal
```

Comment: this is right result, but can i write it without partition ?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from using window function since that is the optimal way for your requirement?

Comment: yes, unfortunately i can't use that. i need to get same result with standard aggregate function only

Answer (score 0):

`join` Region table again your query.

```
select * 
from  Region
left join(
SELECT   T.RegionID, T.ProductID, MAX(T.Quantity) AS MaxOrders
FROM(
    SELECT Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID, SUM([Order Details].Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM Region
    JOIN Territories ON Region.RegionID = Territories.RegionID
    JOIN EmployeeTerritories ON Territories.TerritoryID = EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID
    JOIN Employees ON EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
    JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
    JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
    GROUP BY Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID
) T
--WHERE T.RegionID = 1
GROUP BY T.RegionID, T.ProductID
 ) A on A.RegionID =  Region.RegionID
```

Comment: i need to find only one product with max quantity with region

Answer (score 0):

Cross apply should help for this.

```
Select R.RegionId, C.ProductId, C.MaxOrders From Region R
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 T.RegionID, T.ProductID, MAX(T.Quantity) AS MaxOrders
    FROM(
      SELECT Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID, SUM([Order 
      Details].Quantity) AS 
     Quantity
    FROM Region
    JOIN Territories ON Region.RegionID = Territories.RegionID
    JOIN EmployeeTerritories ON Territories.TerritoryID = 
  EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID
   JOIN Employees ON EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
   JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
   JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
   GROUP BY Region.RegionID, [Order Details].ProductID
 ) T
WHERE T.RegionID = R.RegionId
GROUP BY T.RegionID, T.ProductID
ORDER BY MaxOrders DESC ) C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in an aggregation query.  This looks like:

```
SELECT RegionID, ProductID, Quantity AS MaxOrders
FROM (SELECT t.RegionID, od.ProductID, 
             SUM(od.Quantity) AS Quantity,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.RegionID ORDER BY SUM(od.Quantity) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Territories t JOIN
           EmployeeTerritories et
           ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID JOIN
           Employees e
           ON et.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID JOIN
           Orders o
           ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID JOIN
           [Order Details] od
           ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
      GROUP BY t.RegionID, od.ProductID
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY MaxOrders DESC;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `Region` table is unnecessary because the column you need is in `Territories`.
- No aggregation is needed in the outer query, just filtering.

Comment: This is a good answer but unfortunately, OP wants a query without window function.